# How to check subscription active or not in Stripe - Flask?

Tags: flask, stripe-payments

I have a flask website and I am using Stripe to track my customer subscriptions.

I want to know how do websites track if a user subscription plan is active or not? Currently what I do is, I retrieve the subscription list with filter on customer and see if it is active before when user visits any page. I am sure that is not the way to do it because I have to call the API on each page visit.

```
def check_subs(cust):
    subs = stripe.Subscription.list(customer=cust)
    if subs['data'][0]['status'] == 'active':
         return 1
    return 0


@app.route('/home')
def home_page():
    if check_subs(session['id']) == 0:
         flash("User subscription expired")
         return redirect(url_for('payment_page'))
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard_page():
    if check_subs(session['id']) == 0:
         flash("User subscription expired")
         return redirect(url_for('payment_page'))
    return render_template('dashboard.html')
```

I do have a webhook but don't know how can I utilize that for checking if user subscription is active before rendering a page

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to store your customer’s subscription’s status in your application (aka database).

I recommend you to set up webhooks. They enable you to be notified in real time when events happen on your Stripe account rather than polling for the latest updates manually on your own (retrieve the subscription list with filter on customer)
You can learn more about how webhooks work here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks

In your case, I suggest that you listen to the event [invoice.paid](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-invoice.paid) in order to get notified that the subscription is paid and then you can update the customer access expiration date in your application. You can refer to this link for further details:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#active-subscriptions

So once your page loads, you do a check from your database to know if the customer is eligible to have access to your product or not.

Comment: Then even in my application I will have to make a call yo my database everything to check if they have an active plan or not, right? I use MySQL then before the user visits any page I will have to check my accounts table and see if they have paid or not?

Comment: Yes that's the logic you need to set!